# how to find n'th digit in a number like 1491625....?

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's concatenate the squares of numbers that start with 1. So, what is the n'th digit in this string ?

For example, the 10th digit is 4.

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

It is just an ordinary question that come to mine ordinary mind. How can I solve this to sleep well tonight? any algorithm without looping ?

Comment: Is the function given the ready-made number (`1491625...`) or does it have to compute it itself? Extracting the nth digit should be easy (regardless of the base - but I assume you talk about base 10?).

Comment: @ephemient yes thanks. it is night now. sorry for that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can work enumerate how many 1-digit, 2-digit, 3-digit, etc. numbers there are in this sequence by taking square roots of powers-of-10.  This will allow you to establish which number the *n*-th digit lies in.  From there, it should be pretty trivial.

This should be *O(log n)* complexity.

Comment: +1 A further optimisation is not to calculate the square roots every time, because sqrt(10^n) = sqrt( 10^(n-1) ) * sqrt( 10 ), that's one multiplication per power of 10.

Comment: @biziclop: That's a nice idea!  I guess that numerical inaccuracies would lead this iterative calculation to diverge as `n` gets *really* large, though.

Comment: Yes, in practice with floating point arithmetics it will. But as a theoretical algorithm, it works.

Comment: Another simplification could be applied when you reach the number you need and try to find its square's kth digit. If the number's square is m digits long, you don't have to calculate the square of the number, just its last (m-k+1) digits.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth can you show an example?  from your answer i'm not sure how to implement getDigit(0x87A99C006D61, 10) == 4

Answer (score 3):

ceil(log<sub>10</sub>(x+1)) will give you the number of digits in a number. Iterate through the squares keeping a count of the total length and once you've reached or exceeded the target length n, you know you need the mth digit of the last number for some m (easy to work out). Get the mth digit of this number by dividing by 10<sup>m-1</sup> than taking the last digit with a mod 10.

All-in-all, constant space overhead and O(n) runtime.

Comment: ceil(log10 X+1) is a better estimate (try, for example, ceil(log10 10) and count the digits in 10)..

Comment: Having done the same mistake myself, it was easy(ish) to spot. An alternative is floor(log10 X)+1.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy infinite lists in Haskell make this trivial to express naïvely.

```
ghci> concat [show $ i*i | i <- [1..]] !! 9
'4'
```

Comment: My (revised) alternative proposal:  `concatMap (show . (^2)) [1..]`

Comment: @delnan Plenty of ways to get even more obtuse, like `[1..] >>= show . join (*)` :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this i have used [Python Generators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/). My solution in Python:

```
def _countup(n):
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1

def get_nth_element(n):
    i = 0 # Initialized just to keep track of iterations.
    final_string = ''
    cu_generator = _countup(0)

    while True:
        num = cu_generator.next()
        final_string += str(num * num)
        if len(final_string) > n:
            print "Number of iterations %s" % i
            return final_string[n]
        i += 1
```

RUN:

```
>>> get_nth_element(1000)
Number of iterations 229
'2'

>>> get_nth_element(10000)
Number of iterations 1637
'7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not loop over, taking each number, squaring and incrementing the count from 1 checking at each step if you have reached n? You don't have to keep track of the whole number.
It is a simple simulation exercise. I afraid, I cannot identify a pattern or formula for this.

Comment: There are more effective ways of doing this. Say, you want the two-billionth digit, that's a lot of squaring until you get there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct port of ephemient's Haskell answer to Scala

```
Iterator.from(1).flatMap(x=>(x*x).toString.iterator).drop(9).next
```

returns `4`

O(n)

- `Iterator.from(1)` creates an infinite iterator that counts `1,2,3,4,....`.
- Then `(x*x).toString` computes squares of each of these and turns them into strings.
- `flatMap( ... .iterator)` concatenates these to become an infinite iterator of characters from the sequence in question
- `drop(9)` removes the first 9 elements (indexes 0 thru 8) from the iterator and gives us a new iterator that's waiting at index 9
- `next` gives us that single character.

Comment: I don't understand the code but I'm wonder it is similar linear searching just loop. O(n)